# PDF does not use utf-8 string encoding like Go

Tags: go, pdf, utf-8

I am working with libray (https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf) for Go to process PDF files. By using 'SetReason' method I try to set reason of signing of my pdf file.

```
func (_aggg *PdfSignature )SetReason (reason string ){_aggg .Reason =_gb .MakeString (reason )};
```

This leads to cyrillic text become unclear symbols (as shown in the picture).
[unclear cyricclic symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpsp4.png)

original text is: "русский > Request Id = 12, Task Id = 145"

And it is all ok with cyrillic symbols in main content of PDF file. The problem is in 'Signs'('Подписи') part (as shown in the picture).

In the library there is a mention: (see 'NOTE')

```
// MakeString creates an PdfObjectString from a string.
// NOTE: **PDF does not use utf-8 string encoding like Go so `s` will often not be a utf-8 encoded
// string.**
func MakeString(s string) *PdfObjectString { _aaad := PdfObjectString{_gcae: s}; return &_aaad }
```

I want to my pdf file's 'reason' become readable cyrillic symbols,
so, is there any solutions for this ? Hope, I explained the problem ...

Comment: I read it that both use UTF-8, but with different convention. PDF are more "rendering" then just "text", so they may already get the shaping phase.

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you use `core.MakeEncodedString`
https://apidocs.unidoc.io/unipdf/latest/github.com/unidoc/unipdf/v3/core/#MakeEncodedString

```
signature.Reason = core.MakeEncodedString("русский > Request Id = 12, Task Id = 145", true)
```

> `func MakeEncodedString(s string, utf16BE bool) *PdfObjectString`
> MakeEncodedString creates a PdfObjectString with encoded content, which can be either UTF-16BE or PDFDocEncoding depending on whether `utf16BE` is true or false respectively.

This will store the reason in UTF-16BE which is appropriate for this text.

**Disclosure**: I am the original developer of UniPDF.